# I am using Glide to load the Image From Url

Tags: java, android

Right now I am using glide to load the image from URLs. Now I want to show the Custom progress bar with loading percentage like 50% image is loaded. Is there any way to get the loading time or percentage by using glide or Picasso.

Or if there is not such method then please let me know how I can download the image only of the current position that is visible on screen in the listview.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/TWiStErRob/08d5807e396740e52c90) is the thing you are looking for, you just need to do some customization.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/fbis251/cfa169fd9e1e142e042c, i think this is what you are looking for.